# Link An External JSON Data File In JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsfiddle

Is there a way to link external JSON Data within JSFiddle?

The portion of code that I am attempting to have pull in the JSON Data with is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', url: 'www.myurl.com/js/data/data.json', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

I have seen JSON Data placed within the javascript section/internally placed within the JSFiddle, but I was curious if it was possible to pull in the JSON Data externally using it's url path in JSFiddle.

View the current [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/mxxsvk27/).

Comment: have you read this documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: for ajax requests, plnkr.co is a lot more friendly than fiddle. You create actual files in seconds and point at those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example (including the code in the fiddle) is broken.

You fix it by using this isntead:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.andrewwierzba.com/js/data/data.json', true);
```

Then, however, you hit a brick wall:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.andrewwierzba.com/js/data/data.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How to fix that is for another question and there's a lot of talk about cross-origin XHRs on the net, so try to look it up. It's pain, that's why most people embed the json instead.

---

A better idea may be to use the "echo" feature, as mentioned by @cirtrus in the comment on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a JSON call by using the /echo/json/ URL. In your exemple you must the content of your JSON file

```
{  
    "profiles": [
        { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "female" },
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Akexander", "lastName": "Beth", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Sarah", "lastName": "Kelly", "gender": "female" }
        { "firstName": "Rachel", "lastName": "Haiworth", "gender": "female" }
    ]
}
```

and use it as a parameter to a POST /echo/json/ request.

```
var JSONData = {  
    "profiles": [
        { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "female" },
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Akexander", "lastName": "Beth", "gender": "male" },
        { "firstName": "Sarah", "lastName": "Kelly", "gender": "female" }
        { "firstName": "Rachel", "lastName": "Haiworth", "gender": "female" }
    ]
}

new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode(JSONData),
        delay: 3
    },    
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        // Function to onSucess
    }
}).send();
```

See http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html